# Insert rows into a self referential table with autoincrement

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-insert, self-reference

I want to insert B into A and get C :

```
A :                                    B :
+----+-----------+-------+------+      +-------+--------------+------+
| id | id_parent | value | name |      | value | value_parent | name |
+----+-----------+-------+------+      +-------+--------------+------+
| 1  | NULL      | 11    | a    |      | 21    | 22           | x    |
| 2  | 1         | 12    | b    |      | 22    | 12           | y    |
| 3  | 1         | 13    | c    |      | 23    | 21           | z    |
+----+-----------+-------+------+      +-------+--------------+------+

C : 
+----+-----------+-------+------+
| id | id_parent | value | name |
+----+-----------+-------+------+
| 1  | NULL      | 11    | a    | 
| 2  | 1         | 12    | b    |
| 3  | 1         | 13    | c    |
| 4  | 2         | 22    | y    |
| 5  | 4         | 21    | x    |
| 6  | 5         | 23    | z    |
+----+-----------+-------+------|
```

[Edit : The only constraints are that in both value column there can't be duplicates, and "value_parent" must be a value present in either A or B's value column]

The solution i see right now seems pretty inefficient.

I could group the rows from B so that group 1 contains the rows whose parent values are in A, group 2 contains the rows whose parent values are in group 1, and so on. I could then in turns insert group n and update group n+1 with the ids gotten from the insertion, until i have inserted everything.

```
+-------+-----------+------+
| value | id_parent | name |
+-------+-----------+------+

STEP 1
Group 1
| 22    | 2         | y    |  // find the associated id_parent and insert this group
Group 2
| 21    | NULL      | x    |
Group 3
| 23    | NULL      | z    |

STEP 2
Group 1
| 22    | 2         | y    |
Group 2
| 21    | 4         | x    |  // update this group and insert it
Group 3
| 23    | NULL      | z    |

STEP 3
Group 1 
| 22    | 2         | y    |
Group 2
| 21    | 4         | x    |
Group 3
| 23    | 5         | z    |  // update this group and insert it
+-------+-----------+------+
```

I was wondering if anything more straight forward existed, because i couldn't find anything on the internet. I'm using T-SQL if that's useful.

Answer (score 0):

Table `A` is trivial.  To handle `B`:

```
select new_id, coalesce(id_parent, new_id - 1) as parent_id,
       value_parent as value, name
from (select b.*, a.id as id_parent,
             aa.max_id + row_number() over (order by (case when a.id is not null then 1 else 2 end), b.value) as new_id
      from b cross join
           (select max(id) as max-id from a) aa left join
           a
           on b.value_parent = a.value
     ) b;
```

Comment: small typo, that's a b.value in the order by, not a b.id

Comment: Actually if i'm not wrong, this answer only works in specific cases. Given an element with value v1 and its parent of value v2, the query won't give correct results if v1 > v2, or if there is a element with a parent in B of value v3 such that v1 < v3 < v2.

Comment: @aymericfraise . . . This answers the question that you asked.  The parents don't seem to be defined for the rest of the "b" records, unless I was missing something.

Answer (score 0):

Given that id_parent can be null, i found a solution that works in two steps :

First, add all the rows from B into A with id_parent set to null. Then, update all the rows that were inserted with the correct id_parent.

```
insert into A
select null,value,name from B

update A
set
    id_parent = T.id_parent
from (
    select 
          A.id
        , Ap.id as id_parent
    from B
    inner join A on A.value = B.value
    inner join A Ap on Ap.value = B.value_parent
) as T
where A.id = T.id
```